# Typescript Specify return type as one or multiple from state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I specify that the return type will be one or many from my state: IMyContainerState?
In the code below I've typed the return type to object `{}` | null...
Rather than `{}` I'd like to specify an interface or some sort of 
PICK statement.

What I'm trying to figure out is the syntax when Pick could be 
just one of the state properties or many of the state properties.

```
interface IMyContainerState {
    redirect: boolean;
    request: boolean;
    notify: void;
    totalCount: number;
}


public static getDerivedStateFromProps: IArrowFunction
    = (nextProps: IMyContainerProps, prevState: IMyContainerState): {} | null => {
        if (!!nextProps.data.request && nextProps.data.request !== prevState.request) {

            // what if this code returned request AND redirect properties from state?
            return { request: nextProps.data.request };

        } else { return null; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use the `Partial<IMyContainerState>` type ? [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)